# Can someone help me understand Strands of Power's sorcerer package?

Tags: strands-of-fate

I've tallied up the points and I keep ending up at 7 ap or 70 exp. I'm just not sure if I'm missing something or if it's a typo.

I was also wondering how they came up with the costs for the Discipline points and rotes provided. I figured it's a 1:1 ratio for the discipline points, but I haven't read anything to confirm it. I think I remember reading that you get one rote per affinity point you have, so the discipline points cover five, but what about the sixth? Are you paying 1 ap for one rote instead of the .5 ap or 5 exp?

I've been at it pretty hard setting up a game and reading the books so I have a feeling it will be something very simple that I'm overlooking. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your question looks good to me, but please take a moment to read the [tour] and the [help] to get an idea of how we're different to other sites.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also new to Strands, so I might be missing the same thing you are, but I think the discrepancies you noticed might just be errors on the writer's part. I've only read through it once, but the core book is not very well edited. There are a number of typos and duplicate lines, so it wouldn't surprise me if their math was off here.

As for the discipline points, you are correct that they're a 1:1 thing. The disciplines are just attributes with a special name, so they cost 10xp/1ab.